# Generate embed code given any url

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My goal is to take user-submitted urls and generate video embed code. Any ideas on this could be done?

I've seen multiple sites do this including myvidster. Autoembed is a paid option written in php, however I"m using ruby/rails.

Comment: Do you need it to be able to handle videos from any site or just a predefined set of sites?

Comment: Ideally any site. I've done a lot of thinking about this, I may have to start with supporting a single site. Then expand until I have conditional solutions for most sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) and its [associated Ruby gem](https://github.com/judofyr/ruby-oembed). It supports Youtube, Vimeo, Hulu, blip.tv out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this yourself you will need to parse the URL for each site you are trying to accept video content from. For instance a Youtube link could be used something like this:

```
if url.match(/.*\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(.{11})/) || url.match(/youtu\.be\/(.{11})/)
      %{<iframe width="440" height="275" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{$1}?rel=0&wmode=transparent"></iframe>}.html_safe
else #other video site conditions here
end
```

Where `url` is the string passed in by the user and `$1` is the the ID you parsed out and the iframe string code is specific to the site you are using.